# On time clicker JAVA code error

Tags: java, timer, onclick, schedule

Not understand WHY SCHEDULE underline always and not working (  I tried separated into classes, same thing, just can't get where the problem is.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

```
 import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;


    public class assertion extends JFrame {

     JTextField curTime, xT, yT;
     Timer timer;

     public static void main(String[] args){ 

      new assertion();

     }


     public assertion() {

      JFrame window = new JFrame("ВИ Кликер");
      window.setSize(400,400);

      JPanel mainframe=new JPanel();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);




            JLabel x=new JLabel();
            x.setText("X-Coordinate");
            mainframe.add(x);

            xT=new JTextField(10);
            mainframe.add(xT);
            window.getContentPane().add(mainframe);
            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);



            JLabel y=new JLabel();
            y.setText("Y-Coordinate");
            mainframe.add(y);

            yT=new JTextField(10);
            mainframe.add(yT);
            window.getContentPane().add(mainframe);
            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);



            JLabel time=new JLabel();
            time.setText("Time");
            mainframe.add(o);

            curTime = new JTextField(10);
            mainframe.add(curTime);
            window.getContentPane().add(mainframe);
            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);




            JButton gO =new JButton();
            gO.setText("GO");
            mainframe.add(gO);


            gO.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         timer();
             }
          });


     }


     public void timer(){


      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
      calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      Date time = calendar.getTime();

      timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(new assertion(), time);

     }

     public void mouse() throws AWTException {

      String xx = xT.getText(), yy = yT.getText();
      int xxx = Integer.parseInt(xx), yyy = Integer.parseInt(yy);


      Robot robot = new Robot();
      robot.mouseMove(xxx, yyy);
      robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
      robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
     }


    }
```

Comment: "_not working_" is no information. Never forget to include the complete error message in the question.

Comment: SCHEDULE underline always and not working ---- it's actually mean that I can't run it....... cause of the word SCHEDULE

Comment: if you put your mouse over the error, you should see a meaningful error message. Post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Timer` is ambiguous between `java.util.Timer` and `javax.swing.Timer` so `timer.schedule` cannot be resolved.

Remove the package import

```
import java.util.*;
```

and only import the classes you need specifically, for example

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

`javax.swing.Timer` is the correct `Timer` to use with Swing so you will need to refactor your code to account for this. There's no need to create a new instance of `assertion` - just ensure that all the methods are invoked the Swing Timer `ActionListener`.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // perform timer actions 
    }
});
```

Aside: Java Naming conventions show that classes start with an *uppercase* letter, e.g. `Assertion`

Comment: Ye, that fix the problem, BUT now need to import something for calendar, if I will import specifically for Date, schedule underline again

Comment: Just import the specific classes that you need from `java.util` to avoid conflicts

Comment: Still have the DATE (( and If i will add specifically for DATE schedule underlined again.

Comment: As stated above you need to refactor to suit the [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assertion does not extend TimerTask which is needed.

Create an anonymous class like I showed you in the other question thread.